# Interdigital Capacitor's Capacitance

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, interdigital

I want to calculate the capacitance of an IDC and I am using this calculator: https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/interdigital-capacitor-calculator.html

It has a couple of different inputs and it outputs C in pF / cm. I have seen an answer where they tell you to multiply this by the length of the line snaking through the passage itself, but if that's so then why does this paper's capacitance values don't line up when I use the given dimensions and dielectric in the formula?
Paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1131429

This paper has the specifications all over the place so you might have to look a little.

Ultimately, I just want to know if using the formula and then multiplying with passage length is the right way or not, and if the paper's method is different or something.